# Grails how to get my form/textbox value inside each

Tags: javascript, grails

I have this code where i want to compare a value from database to the value enter in the form field by the user

```
   function checkFromIndex(form){           
       <g:each in="${index}">
           <g:if test="${it.indexDate == form.endDate.value}">
               alert("pass")
           </g:if>
       </g:each>         
   }
```

but when i use this if statement , it never recognize this form.endDate (outside each it do)

Any solution

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My quick solution:

```
function checkFromIndex(form){
  var endDate = form.endDate.value; //have to be Numeric type
  var lst = ${[[id:1,indexDate:new Date().getTime()],[id:2,indexDate:new Date().getTime()],[id:3,indexDate:new Date().getTime()]] as grails.converters.JSON}
  jQuery.each(lst, function(i,v) { if (v.indexDate == endDate) {alert ('pass!')}});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Grails tags are evaluated server-side, before serving your page to the browser. So you cannot use javascript variables or functions inside them. That's why your usage of JS expression `form.endDate.value` inside `<g:if>` is incorrect.

They can still be used to produce javascript that is to be evaluated on client-side. You can write your function like this:

```
function checkFromIndex(form) {
    <g:each in="${index}">
        if (${it.indexDate} == form.endDate.value) {
            alert("pass")                       
        }
    </g:each>
}
```

That way, server-side evaluation of `<g:each>` results in generating a body for `checkFromIndex`, with one JS `if` statement for each indexDate in `index` model variable. Bear in mind that for large `index` resulting HTML will be long; you may want to consider outputting `index` as an JS array, and use its `indexOf` method instead:

```
function checkFromIndex(form) {
    if (${index*.indexDate as JSON}.indexOf(form.endDate.value) >= 0) {
        alert("pass")                       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the original value into a hidden field within the html-form and then do a plain javascript routine, which compares the original values (= value of the hidden field) to the actual entered values, like this:

```
function validate() {
    var result = true;        
    $(".originalValue").each(function(i, item) {
         var inputName = $(item).attr("name").replace("_original", "");
         if ($(item).val() != $("#"+inputName).val()) {
            result = false;
         }
    });
    if (result) alert("Everything the same");
}
```

Your form will look like:

```
<g:textField name="date" value="${date}"/>
<g:hiddenField name="date_original" class="orginalValue" value="${date}" />
```

If your input element's names contain "." you need to escape those, before you can select them using `$(...)`.